# how to count the occurance of a string in a column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Say I have the following column:

```
apple
orange
banana
apple
apple
```

what is the formula so I can get the count of 'apple' in that column, so in this case it would result in 3.

Answer (score 3):

Following formula will give you count of any mentioned text:

=COUNTIF(range,"text")

Mention the range and replace **text** with apple.

**Example:**
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"apple")

You can read more about this by visiting following URL:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214153